# bxSlider - using getCurrentSlide to create custom caption

Tags: jquery, bxslider

I am trying to create a caption that updates and corresponds with each passing slide, outside of the bxSlider.  I'm attempting to use getCurrentSlide(); to do this, but the caption gets stuck on "Caption TWO" after the second slide.

Here is my JavaScript:

```
var bxSlider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();

$(document).on('click', function(){
    var current = bxSlider.getCurrentSlide();
    if (current = 0) {
        $('p.custom_caption').html('Caption ONE');
     }
     else if (current = 1) {
        $('p.custom_caption').html('Caption TWO');
     }
     else if (current = 2) {
        $('p.custom_caption').html('Caption THREE');
     }
     else if (current = 3) {
        $('p.custom_caption').html('Caption FOUR');
     }

});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NinoLopezWeb/8k27amfb/7/)

Any help is greatly appreciated!  Thanks!

Comment: in if statement use  double equals (==)

Comment: @dm4web is correct. Change the equals == and your issue is fixed. http://jsfiddle.net/yxL8z6ks/

Answer (score 0):

dm4web is right (see comments) --

```
var bxSlider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();

$(document).on('click', function(){
    var current = bxSlider.getCurrentSlide();
    if (current == 0) {
        $('p.custom_caption').html('Caption ONE');
     }
     else if (current == 1) {
        $('p.custom_caption').html('Caption TWO');
     }
     else if (current == 2) {
        $('p.custom_caption').html('Caption THREE');
     }
     else if (current == 3) {
        $('p.custom_caption').html('Caption FOUR');
     }
});
```